# Evaluating limit outside the integral with the same variable and ignoring the integral value is legal?

Tags: limits

My problem:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\, \left(i\varepsilon\int_{\pi}^{0} e^{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta} t} \log\left(\frac{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}+1}{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}}\right) e^{i\vartheta}\,\mathrm d \vartheta\right)$$

I'm thinking about limit property that allows us to split the multiplication inside the limit
$$\begin{align}
& \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\, \left(i\varepsilon\int_{\pi}^{0} e^{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta} t} \log\left(\frac{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}+1}{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}}\right) e^{i\vartheta}\,\mathrm d \vartheta\right)\\
=& \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\, \left(\varepsilon\right)\cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\, \left(i\int_{\pi}^{0} e^{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta} t} \log\left(\frac{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}+1}{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}}\right) e^{i\vartheta}\,\mathrm d \vartheta\right)\\
=&\, 0\cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\, \left(i\int_{\pi}^{0} e^{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta} t} \log\left(\frac{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}+1}{\varepsilon e^{i\vartheta}}\right) e^{i\vartheta}\,\mathrm d \vartheta\right)\\
=&\,0
\end{align}$$
Now, my problem is i'm not sure if the integral is convergent. Secondly, if i evaluate the second limit, look at the denominator of the logarithm argument. Can i legally do this? Or please help me to think another way such that i get $0$ as the answer. My context is evaluating contour integration along small circle around branch cut. Since i've found the path which contributes the value of the contour integration, This integral when $\varepsilon\to 0$ must be $0$. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can be more precise. With log properties you can move the denominator in the log away and then use squeeze theorem on $\epsilon\log\epsilon$. Everything else is continuous in $\epsilon$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks. But is it $\ln(0)=\infty$ and since i want $0$, can i assume $0\cdot \infty = 0$?

Comment: Oh forget my comment above. I see. Squeeze theorem. Thanks!